# How to use vs2005 libraries in vs2003

Tags: visual-studio

is there is any way to use VS2005 libraries in VS2003.Can any one help me how to use vs2005 libraries in vs2003

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use .NET 2.0 assemblies (I assume we're talking .NET here) in .NET 1.x apps unless you recompile these to target 1.x version of the Framework.